# Can't open Xpages Dialog from a client-side included script

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

It seems the only way to open a client-side dialog is from within an embedded control which doesn't work for me.  Most of my coding to populate the dialogs is contained in an external script library, yet when I try to XSP.openDialog(id) I receive a jumbled javascript error on Firebug.

I have tried

- Accessing the object (an extension library dialog) directly from a button on the xpages.  It opens without a problem
- Calling a script function from an embedded button and passing the id of the dialog.  Error.
- Created a global variable containing the id of the dialog and called directly from a button.  WORKS
- Same global variable, but called in a javascript function.  ERROR
- from within script created variable with dojo.byId.  ERROR

Is there something else I need to configure?  Many of the buttons I will be using are also dynamically generated from a JSON-supplied feed.

Comment: Can you post your code please for how you are defining the global variable for the id, the code in the external function and how you are calling it?

Comment: Be careful with variables you declare in any SSJS script library. They are application wide visible, not just to the current user!

Comment: And yes: code rulez. Edit your question

Comment: Have you tried looking at the extlib sample database from the OpenNTF?  Online example here: http://domino8.strandplatsen.se/openntf/xpagesext.nsf/Core_Dialog.xsp

Comment: Figured it out and it had to do with the naming scheme xpages used.  I created a basic function to get the object:function gE(elm){var a=dojo.query('[id$=":'+elm+'"]');try{return a[0]}catch(e){return null}}